# write a file to /public with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to create a dynamic sitemap for my site, which runs on Zend.

I want one of my controllers to be able to write to the /public directory, but I can't figure out how to get the file written to the right place.

My relevant directory structure is something like:

.application/

....modules/

.......my_module/

..........controllers/

.............SitemapController.php

.library/

.public/

Is this a simple way in Zend to point at the public/ directory without writing something ugly like "file://../../../public/" every time?

Comment: You can create a dynamic sitemap.xml files directly with Zend btw. Furthermore, if you want it dynamically you don't have to store it to the public folder. You don't write HTML files to the public folder, I hope!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zend framework bootstrap defines a constant called **APPLICATION_PATH** following that guideline you can initialize another constant that points to the public path:

```
define('PUBLIC_PATH', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/');
```

This will then be available everywhere. Make sure that the webserver has write permissions to the folder you want to store files in.

Comment: you might want to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of hardcoding the slashes

Comment: One could refer to [`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) as well.

Comment: @marcelog Using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is not necessary at all: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php#73954

Comment: correct, thanks for pointing that out. but that's just because nowadays windows accepts the slash as separator. the constant is still needed when reading paths, but can be skipped when writing them –

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but you shouldn't -- for security, the public dir shouldn't be writable by the process that runs the web server. There are a number of ways around this. You could write the file to some other stand-alone directory outside the document root and then symlink to it. Or maybe just create a route in your app config so that the file gets generated on the fly every time.

Comment: Who says that the user under which PHP runs is the same user the webserver runs under?

Comment: Doesn't matter -- if you're not running an embedded PHP then the doc root still shouldn't be writable by the PHP process owner.